# Sql server cache settings

Tags: sql-server, performance, caching

I have 2 databases. One is an old one created on Microsoft SQL server 2012 but restored to Microsoft sql server 2014

And another one that was created from scratch on Microsoft SQL server 2016 (was migrated).

I ran on both servers (below)

```
  dbcc dropcleanbuffers;
  DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
```

When i run my app on first run it takes 30 mins for each database(a lot of data loading).

Once completed i close my app (making sure there are no active tasks)

I run again this time without clearing the cache. 
SQL 2012 database now takes 4 mins however my SQL2016 database still take 30 mins.

if i run (below) again they both take the same time. (30 mins)

```
  dbcc dropcleanbuffers;
  DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
```

I'm assuming this is a cache issue, so what i would like to know is, where are cache settings on the database / server and how to change them which will allow the sql 2016 database to perform the same as SQL 2012 database?

> > i am using winforms DBCommand and using ExecuteNonQuery() for query execution, I'm using SSMS to connect to sql server to view the database.

Thank you

Comment: (Reply to your removed comment)My assumption is wrong? for you to make that decision means the information above i provided was sufficient and asked well enough for you to understand it. @M.Ali

Comment: Enough information to rule out cache as the bottleneck but not enough to identify the actual bottleneck, not saying anymore. Thanks, hope you get this sorted. tar

Comment: ok thanks, if you don't know the answer then that's fine.